# Stacking data into one Column in Excel. Tried TOCOL and VSTACK but it cant ignore formulas or pasted cells. It still leaves gaps

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm Using Office 365

I have a column of 15000 rows that return values dependant on a formula. That part works fine.
*(I have several columns but if I get one working I can apply it to the rest)*

I want to condense this down into another a column with all the data sequential. This is to save scanning thousands of rows and have it all summarised.

e.g
A is the formula containing cells. Some cells in column will be blank depending on other conditions.
B has the formula =TOCOL(A1:A11) in only cell B1. The formula auto completes all the way down the B column until it runs out of data from the A column. Basically stacking the data in column B

The result I am getting is a duplicate of column A including the gaps. TOCOL has a switch that rejects blank cells etc but that does not work on Formula cells or on pasted cells even if blank.

If I delete the contents of any blank cells then the formula works.

Obviously not ideal on a 15000 value column.

Column A has a formula in it. I tried various forms of formula cell rejection in conjunction with the TOCOL and VSTACK formulas but nothing has worked. "IFERROR etc". I am sure that doesn't work with either formula. The formulas TOCOL and VSTACK only occupy one cell and operate on the entire column below the formula.

I have tried creating a helper column where I used "paste values", and "paste link". Neither of those worked.

I tried "=IF(A1="", "", A1)" Basically show null if a A1 is blank otherwise show the value in A1.
The TOCOL column "C" say, dispalys blanks where the cells are blank in B instead of condensing the data.

I got this working in Excel 2016 using a huge formula that now means excel crawls and has made it unworkable across the 10 columns the formula operates in. TOCOL and VSTACK are only available in 365.

The spreadsheet needs to remain dynamic as the formula cell values change depending on various other conditions. A macro or formula to clear the contents of all non value fields isn't a solution.

I'm hoping that this is easily solved. It should be a simple thing I'd have thought. With manually entered values TOCOL and VSTACK work perfect fine. Any ideas? Exhausted my knowledge now. ChatGPT has no knowledge of VSTACK or TOCOL. Any formula suggestions would be awesome. I reviewed similar questions but none had gaps in the data they were processing.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without seeing your data and your expected output it is very hard to help you. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: May not be much help, as I am struggling with exactly the same issue with no real resolution.  I have been exploring the CELL("contents" function to only look at the the results of the formula and not the formula itself.

    =IF(ISBLANK(CELL("contents",A1)),,CELL("contents",A1))

But this is circular and still produces blanks.